# TM-U220B escpos supporting the bigger font size (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, thermal-printer, escpos

Is there any possible way to print bigger font size in TM-U220B by using escpos (Python3) ? I have tried so many time and yet still cannot print bigger font size or image as well.
Thank you very much if you could helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the following commands can be used with TM-U220.
It seems that you can specify 3 types of double width, double height, and double width height, but it may not be supported.
Please try it.
It may be possible to double width.
[ESC !](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=23)

There are two types that can be specified for image printing: 8-dot single-density or 8-dot double-density.
And it seems that it only expands in the width direction, not in the height direction.
[ESC *](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=88)
[FS q [obsolete command]](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=90)
[FS p [obsolete command]](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=89)

Please click the TM-U220 button in the `Select your printer model [-]` table on each of the above pages for model-dependent details.

---

In addition:

This is a QA article for other POS apps, but it seems that enlarged printing is possible.
[Epson TM U220 font size](https://forum.sambapos.com/t/epson-tm-u220-font-size/766)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try those commands first ! Its took me a lot of time for testing. ~